# I have data for couple of projects in excel - 367x58. I tried multiple functions, however the file gets imported as a list

Tags: r, dataframe, listview, import, file-type

Code:

```
library(hms)
install.packages("hms")

library(pillar)
install.packages("pillar")

AS_0 <- read.csv2(file ="XYZ.csv", head = TRUE, sep=",", row.names = NULL, skipNul = TRUE)
AS_1 <- as.data.frame(AS_0)
```

#

Output:

```
> AS_0 <- read.csv2(file ="XYZ.csv", head = TRUE, sep=",", row.names = NULL, skipNul = TRUE)
> AS_1 <- as.data.frame(AS_0)
> 
> typeof(AS_1)
[1] "list"
```

#

Other Options explored

1. Import file type - .xlsx, .csv, .txt
2. Read functions - read.csv(), read.csv2()
3. as.dataframe(), as.dataframe.as.dataframe()

Comment: Try looking at `class()` rather than `typeof()`. `typeof` only tells you the storage type which doesn't really tell you how the object behaves. And data.frames are really just fancy lists. What problems does this list cause exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the response MrFlick. I am just comfortable working with dataframes (would be a good time mention that I am a beginner at R, so try to follow what I have learned). I did not know that lists are dataframes! But the class() is indeed dataframe. Thanks again.